# how can one run video.js in phantomjs browser

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, video.js

I was trying to automate phantomjs using selenium when I encountered that the page that was loading had a video.js tag and was trying to play a video.

Please suggest me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PhantomJS doesn't support html5 video: [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html) You could try to use [polyfills](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10839#issuecomment-265457754), but to really get video support, you're probably should switch to other browser drivers for Selenium, like Firefox or Chrome.